# outputting javascript in php using echo

Tags: php, javascript

can somebody tell me why this does not work:

```
<script>
<?
echo 'oaktree.addItem("test1", branch1, "")';
echo 'oaktree.addItem("test2", branch1, "")';
?>
</script>
```

When i take this out of PHP, it works like expected but when doing echo in does nothing...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `;` behind the function:

```
<script>
<?
echo 'oaktree.addItem("test1", branch1, "");';
echo 'oaktree.addItem("test2", branch1, "");';
?>
</script>
```

`echo` does not automatically include a new line. The above would echo as:

```
oaktree.addItem("test1", branch1, "");oaktree.addItem("test1", branch1, "");
```

Which is why the `;` is mandatory for it to work. You can also include a new line yourself but adding a `;` by default is a better approach.

You could have probably spotted this error by looking at the source of the page or opening up the console.